# How to append 50 mb data(From text file) in jtextArea in java?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a big file which is having 50 mb data.I want to read and append into jTextArea(). But i am getting **out of **memory error**** while appending data.How can i do this?please anyone help me

example:

```
BufferedReader br;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\myFile.txt"));
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                   // process the line.
                    builder.append(line);// here getting error
                }
                System.out.println(builder.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
JTextArea jt = new JtextArea();
jt.append(builder.toString();
```

Comment: 50 MB raw text is like 35 Bibles! Why do you need this amount of text in one field? reading it would take me years ;)

Comment: I want to read this file and to display in textarea or any other component.How to display whole datas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set up the max size of your JVM

Answer (score 2):

Either you can increase the maximum heap size, or you can use the paginator design pattern.

Pagination works by loading only those data that are actually visible. So if your text area can display two pages of text, you load only those two displayed pages of text at a time. If the user scrolls down, you throw away loaded pages and load those new two. That way, you will always have only two pages in memory at a time.

Comment: Does Swing actually expose this in a useful fashion? Because what I'm finding is that if the user suddenly scrolls to down near the bottom, you now have to somehow figure out how far down they are. It seems like as an absolute minimum, someone has to read all of the text to figure out how many view lines each model line takes up.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there will ever be a user to read the 50MB of text that you would add to your `JTextArea`.

I suggest you implement some sort of pagination and only add a few 100s or 1000s of lines at once.

However, if you really want to add all the text then set the `-Xmx` parameter of your application to something higher.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring that it is impractical in terms of usability (and JTextArea will probably not perform well with that much text), you can make some changes to your code to reduce the amount of memory needed (You probably still need to increase -Xmx).

Your first lever is to properly size the StringBuilder for the amount of data you want to put into it. Replacing the *new StringBuilder()* with *new StringBuilder(sizeOfFile)* will avoid allocating more memory than needed (this may make a difference of several MB, due to StringBuilders internal memory allocation policy method).

Now when you do *builder.toString()*, you should be aware that this will *double* the amount of memory required, since everything in the builder is *copied* to create the String. With the normal Swing API, there is no way around that, since you absolutely *need* a String.

But you can change that - look at how the JTextArea works internally: the JTextArea does not really store the text it works with - storing of the text is delegated to a model object, in this case of type javax.swing.Document. If you take a look at Document, you'll find that its an interface. Normally when you use a JTextArea, it creates its own, private document which is not really intended for such large amounts of data (javax.swing.PlainDocument). Now the PlainDocument in turn works with a javax.swing.Content (again an interface), normally implemented in javax.swing.StringContent. This you can replace with your own, new content class that works with a StringBuilder directly (that way there would be no need to duplicate data in memory).

So, you can implement your own Content class working with StringBuilder and construct your JTextArea this way:

```
Content c = new StringBuilderContent(builder);
Document d = new PlainDocument(c);
JTextArea jt = new JTextArea(d);
```

Actually creating and implementing StringBuilderContent is left as an excercise to the reader. Actually, you could also implement Content to directly work with a file, that way you could handle files much larger than available heap, too.

Comment: I'm trying this at the moment, but nothing but fires all over the place so far. It looks like my content object only gets called asking for the first byte and for some reason Swing doesn't ever ask for any more. :/